# Do I have an error with throwing errors? What should I do?

Tags: swift, error-handling, switch-statement

I recently tried to run this code

```swift
extension String: Error {} //string isn't throw-able by default 

func throwingFunction() throws { //this function always throws on call. So far so good
    throw "error"
}

switch try throwingFunction() {
    case "error": print("It works!") //but it doesn't 
    default: break
}
```

The error is `expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type '()'`
Shouldn't this function return raw string? Am I doing something wrong? Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`throwingFunction()` returns `Void` aka `()` if it not throwing an error.
You can't switch on a `Void`.

So you need to `try` to execute the function and catch the `error` then you can switch on the `error` itself.

```
do {
    try throwingFunction()
} catch {
    switch error as! String { // Since you know the error type, It's perfectly safe to force unwrap
    case "error": print("It works!")
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, that worked. Seems like error handling is overshugarized in swift imo. I expected behavior to be like with return. ```func throwingFunction(){ return "error"}```

Comment: You're welcome, not at all when you get used to it. Swift is the most beautiful language I ever seen. ;)